# A way to bypass the 255 character limit in my code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Word document where the user will input codes for standard comments, usually using an outline format like bullets 1, a, 2, and 3. The user saves and closes the Word document. Then the user can open a Comments Excel document and click on a button that will ask the user to find which Word document they want to replace the codes (column A) with the Text value (column C) in the Excel document. The code and process work great except when the value exceeds 255 characters, which will happen quite often. I've read about using the clipboard in doing this, but I wasn't sure how to implement it into my existing code. Thank you for any help. Sorry if I am not posting this correctly, new to this forum.

---

Sample comments in Word:

1. B401
2. B402
3. M317
4. This is my own comment
5. P203

---

Sample in Excel file (each row separated by a comma):

- Column A rows- B401, B402, M317, P201, P203
- Column B rows- Handrail compliance, Handrail Extensions, HVAC, Water Building, Water System
- Column C rows-
  Handrails shall comply with section 1014 of the 2015 International Building Code.,
  Handrails shall return to a wall guard or walking surface. (See Section 1014.6 of the 2015 International Building Code.),
  No HVAC drawings shown; will handle in the field.,
  Where water pressure within a building exceeds 80 psi (552 kPa) static, an approved water pressure reducing valve conforming to ASSE 1003 or CSA B356 with strainer shall be installed to reduce the pressure in the building water distribution piping to 80 psi (552 kPa) static or less. Exceptions to this requirement are service lines to sill cocks and outside hydrants, and main supply risers where pressure from the mains is reduced to 80 psi (552 kPa) or less at individual fixtures.  (See Section 604.8 of the 2015 International Plumbing Code.),
  A water test shall be applied to the drainage system either in its entirety or in sections.  If applied to the entire system, all openings in the piping shall be tightly closed, except the highest opening, and the system shall be filled with water to point of overflow.  If the system is tested in sections, each opening shall be tightly plugged except the highest openings of the section under test, and each section shall be filled with water, but no section shall be tested with less than a 10-foot (3048 mm) head of water.  In testing successive sections, at least the upper 10 feet (3048 mm) of the next preceding section shall be tested so that no joint or pipe in the building, except the uppermost 10 feet (3048 mm) of the system, shall have been submitted to a test of less than a 10-foot (3048 mm) head of water. The water shall be kept in the system, or in the portion under test, for at least 15 minutes before inspection starts.  The system shall then be tight at all points.  (See Section 312.2 of the 2015 International plumbing Code.)  Plastic piping shall not be tested with air. An air test shall be made by forcing air into the system until there is a uniform gauge pressure of 5 pounds per square inch (psi) (34.5 kPa) or sufficient to balance a 10-inch (254 mm) column of mercury.  This pressure shall be held for a test period of at least 15 minutes.  Any adjustments to the test pressure required because of changes in ambient temperature or the seating of gaskets shall be made prior to the beginning of the test period.  (See Section 312.3 of the 2015 International Plumbing Code)

---

Existing Excel Code that works until the 255 character limit:

```
Sub Replace()
 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Filters.Add "Word Files", "*.docx; *.docm", 1
  .Show
  fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
 End With
Dim pathh As String
Dim pathhi As String
Dim oCell  As Integer
Dim from_text As String, to_text As String
Dim WA As Object

pathh = fullpath

Set WA = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WA.Documents.Open (pathh)
WA.Visible = True

For oCell = 1 To 500
 from_text = Sheets("Comments").Range("A" & oCell).Value
 to_text = Sheets("Comments").Range("C" & oCell).Value
 With WA.ActiveDocument
  Set myRange = .Content
  With myRange.Find
   .Execute FindText:=from_text, ReplaceWith:=to_text, Replace:=1
  End With
 End With
Next oCell
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about *what* doesn't work. Is it the `.Execute` line? This has been asked, and answered, very often. So often, I can't even post a list of links. In the site's "Search" bar use the following to get a listing: `[ms-word] [vba] replace 255`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String too long, copying data from Excel into a Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742174/string-too-long-copying-data-from-excel-into-a-word-document)

Comment: Cindy, sorry, yes I get the Run-time error '5854': String parameter too long. on the line: 
.Execute FindText:=from_text, ReplaceWith:=to_text, Replace:=1 with the error code 
Let me look at the link your provided. Thank you.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thank you for the link. I'm afraid I am lost with how to incorporate it into my code but I will continue to browse the search forums to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fault is in the function you are using which can't accept a parameter of the size you want.  So, we have to work around it a bit.  Try replacing your for loop with this:

```
For oCell = 1 To 500
    from_text = Sheets("Comments").Range("A" & oCell).Value
    to_text = Sheets("Comments").Range("C" & oCell).Value

    If from_text = "" Then Exit For

    WA.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    WA.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With WA.Selection.Find
        .Text = from_text
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = 1
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    IF WA.Selection.Find.Execute Then
        WA.Selection = to_text
    End If
Next oCell
```

The goal here is just to use find to select the "from" text, and then assign that selection with the intended "to" text value.  This avoids the replace function itself.  Tested successfully on my end.  The code more closely matches what Word generates in its macro recorder, however some VBA constants have been replaced with numeric values, so buyer beware.

Hope it helps

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking to do. I did have to change the 1 to 500 to be the exact range of my list in Excel for it to work and it did wonderfully. Thank you very much. I tried to upvote you as well, but it said I didn't have enough reupation.

Comment: Oh boy, looks like I was missing something. Not all of the codes will be used in the excel document. For example, the user could use B401, B402, then use P203, thus skipping using M317 and P201. But when I use the code, it seems to be setup as if I am going to use all of the codes.

Comment: It looks like there were some bugs.  See if the edits above help.  There's now a line that halts the loop when it runs out of records to process.  Also,  WA.Selection.Find.Execute is wrapped in an IF THEN so replacements only happen when the target text is actually found.  Very sorry!  I hope it didn't cause you too much grief.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was looking for. Thank you very much. Just wanted to verify though, the codes are grouped, for example B1 through B17, P1 through P32, so if the user were to put in P32, it was finding the P3 code and using the text for it. Should I turn on: [.MatchWholeWord = True] to get it to find the instance of P32?

Comment: Yes, set [MatchWholeWorld=True] to avoid those partials.  In an ideal world it wouldn't be "B1" but "B001".  Alas.